# Devise Confirmation mail is being sent again

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, devise

The confirmation mail is being resent again, even after email confirmation. The devise users attribute unconfirmed_email doesn't change to NULL value even though the confirmed_at attribute displays the time it was confirmed.

I'm using rails 5 and devise gem version `4.2`

This is confirmation controller

```
 def create
  begin
  email = params[resource_name][:email]
  rescue
  email = ""
end
user = User.find_by_email(email)
if poster and ["blocked", "deactivated"].include?(user.status)
  poster.errors.add(:email, "has been #{user.status}")
  self.resource = user
  respond_with(self.resource)
  return false
end
super
end
```

This is function verify email in registrations controller .

```
 def verify_email
   @user = User.find_by_confirmation_token(params[:token])
if @user
  if @user.confirmed?
    flash[:error] = "Your Account is already verified please try to login"
    redirect_to new_poster_session_path
  else
    @user.confirmed_at = Time.now
    #@user.confirmation_token = nil
    @user.save
    sign_in @user
    token = Devise.friendly_token
    current_user.update_attribute :current_sign_in_token, token
    session[:sign_in_token] = token
    redirect_to root_path
  end
else
  @user = User.new
  @company = Company.new
  @city = City.new
  #      @region = Location::Region.new
  flash.now[:error] =       I18n.t("applicant.confirmations.invalid_or_expired_token")
  flash[:regenerate_token] = I18n.t("applicant.confirmations.invalid_or_expired_token_regenerate", :path => new_user_confirmation_path)
  respond_with_navigational(resource) { render :new }
end
```

end

The above code works well with another model and since no error is being displayed. I do not know how to go about it. Please help !

Answer (score 1):

If this is the actual code, you have an error.

Change this line

```
user = user.find_by_email(email)
```

to this line

```
user = User.find_by_email(email) # use the class!
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad ,typo error . It is as "User" only,but no clue as to why it's not working.